# Making pandas fillna persistent

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I am working with some csv datasets that do contain missing data, which is marked as *Lücke*.

I import the datasets as follows:

```
MyData=pd.read_csv('filename.csv',sep=';',skiprows=19,index_col='Date',dayfirst=True,parse_dates=True, na_values='L\xfccke')
```

Which works as expected, turning the *Lücke* into the more familiar *NaN*.

Looking at the tail of it, where I know that there is a Lücke, i get the following, as expected:

```
                     level
Date                      
2011-12-28 07:00:00    0.0
2011-12-29 07:00:00    0.0
2011-12-30 07:00:00    0.4
2011-12-31 07:00:00    0.0
2012-01-01 07:00:00    NaN
```

So according to the pandas documentation (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/missing_data.html#filling-missing-values-fillna) a simple

```
In [23]: MyData.level.fillna(0)
```

should to the trick. And its

```
Out [24]:
Date
...
2011-12-29 07:00:00       0.0
2011-12-30 07:00:00       0.4
2011-12-31 07:00:00       0.0
2012-01-01 07:00:00       0.0
Name: level, Length: 14976
```

seems to indicate it did work.

But continuing, I always got `AttributeError: max must be larger than min in range parameter.` errors, trying to plot a histogram with `plt.hist`.

So to check, I ran a simple `MyData.tail()` and `MyData.level.tail`, and they both got me

```
                     level
Date                      
2011-12-28 07:00:00    0.0
2011-12-29 07:00:00    0.0
2011-12-30 07:00:00    0.4
2011-12-31 07:00:00    0.0
2012-01-01 07:00:00    NaN
```

Where did that come from? Do I misunderstand fillna, and must specify it that it actually should *really* replace NaN, instead of just pretending to?

Or is that a bug with some *old* pandas version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) will return the filled DataFrame and not work on it "in-place", as such you have to do:

```
MyData.level = MyData.level.fillna(0)
```

Alternatively you can pass `inplace=True` when calling it, and it *will* work in-place, so:

```
MyData.level.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Comment: damn, that was too simple. Thank you! Somehow I dont yet get it, when something gets changed persistently (thus making the `Whatever = Whatever + something` unneeded) and when I actually have to do that. What would the purpose of the "wrong" way I did first do it be? I cant seem to access the changes I made in any subsequent steps, hence my question here.